# Simultaneous bold and italic text in bokeh

Tags: python, font-face, bokeh

How can I specify that I want text (say an axis title) to be both bold and italic in bokeh?

This is bold: `text_font_style = 'bold'`

This is italic: `text_font_style = 'italic'`

How do I do both simultaneously? I assume this is possible because of this response on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/596#issuecomment-411820584)

Some things I have tried without success include:

```
text_font_style = 'bolditalic'
text_font_style = 'bold+italic'
text_font_style = ('bold', 'italic')
text_font_style = set('bold', 'italic')

# together (in a last ditch effort):
text_font_style = 'bold'
text_font_style = 'italic'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 0.13 this does not appear to be possible. The [`FontStyle` enum](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/bd68676bd5b84dafb2f70e959be88dce29ce53cc/bokeh/core/enums.py#L146) is currently defined as:

```
FontStyle = enumeration("normal", "italic", "bold")
```

Which means that a Bokeh `text_font_style` property will only accept any *one* on those, i.e. you can only have bold *or* italic, but not both. I would describe this as a simple oversight that no one has noticed until now. I think fixing this would be as simple as adding new values for the combinations, e.g. `"italic bold"`, to the enum value (and fixing up some some related tests), so I would encourage you to submit a [new feature request issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).